# SQL Join on ID and Date

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm a little stumped with how to perform a join based on a date and sku.

I have 3 tables one containing order information, one with line items and one with costs

I'm able to join line items and order info to get the following:

```
Sku    | Price  | Date
------ | ------ | -----
ABC1   | 3.99   | 2016-11-01
ABC2   | 2.99   | 2016-10-01
ABC1   | 3.99   | 2016-10-01
ABC3   | 5.99   | 2016-11-01
```

I need to join on to this the cost of the goods based on the date of the order

This sits in a costs table which looks like the following:

```
Sku    | Cost   | Valid_from | Valid_to
------ | ------ | ---------- | ----------
ABC1   | 1.99   | 2016-11-01 | NULL
ABC2   | 0.99   | 2015-10-01 | NULL
ABC1   | 2.99   | 2015-10-01 | 2016-10-30 
ABC3   | 3.99   | 2015-11-01 | 2016-10-30
```

Some of the skus have several cost records and have start and end dates, others have a single start date and no end date.

I'm struggling to look up the sku, then look to find the corresponding date

```
Sku    | Price  | Date       | Cost
------ | ------ | ---------- | -----
ABC1   | 3.99   | 2016-11-01 | 1.99
ABC2   | 2.99   | 2016-10-01 | 0.99
ABC1   | 3.99   | 2016-10-01 | 2.99
ABC3   | 5.99   | 2016-11-01 | 3.99
```

I'm probably trying over engineer it but can't seem to get close to joining these and getting back the relevant info.

Any help appriciated

Comment: For the line item with SKU `ABC3` there is no corresponding cost entry (2016-11-01 is after the end of the cost range for ABC3). So either your expected output is wrong or the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a date range on the fly and then test if the date from the line item falls into that range:

```
select li.*, c.cost
from line_item li
  join cost c on li.sku = c.sku 
             and li.date <@ daterange(c.valid_from, c.valid_to);
```

Using `NULL` as the upper limit of the range automatically makes it an unbounded range, so there is no need to explicitly deal with `NULL` in the query.

Online example: http://rextester.com/OAJ69387

---

An index on the daterange would probably speed things up:

```
create index on cost using gist (daterange(valid_from, valid_to));
```

---

Note:

For your sample data, the above query will **not** return the cost information for the line item with SKU ABC3 because the date of that line item does not fall into the range defined by the cost row for ABC3. If your sample data is correct, and you do want the line item ABC3 included you need an outer join - but then you wouldn't have a cost value.

Comment: Looking to a tutorial for daterange the index should looks like `CREATE INDEX cars_price_range_idx ON cars USING gist (cost); ` is the same as you wrote it? Looks like creating a `GIST` index on the `cost` column is enough

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: an index on the `cost` column would be completely useless. But you are right, it should be a gist index.

Comment: Sorry I mean the Date column. The example I was looking was for cost between some ranges, and the index was in the cost column. I think right now would create a `range` index instead.

Comment: I think you should have two index, one for `li.date` and another for `cost(Valid_from,Valid_to)`

Comment: Anyone know how to ensure the upper date is inclusive? Any prices that change on the end date are currently excluded within daterange()

Comment: @dan: `daterange(c.valid_from, c.valid_to, '[]');` should do that

Answer (score 0):

You need date inside the ranges. But in this case you need two condition to handle the open ranges.

```
 SELECT io.*, c.Cost
 FROM itemOrder io
 JOIN costs c
   ON io.Sku =  c.Sku
  AND ( (io.Date >= c.Valid_from  and c.Valid_to IS NULL)
     OR (io.Date >= c.Valid_from  and io.Date <= c.Valid_to)
      )                                    -- ^^ this may need to be `<`
                                           -- depend on how you define your ranges
```

Comment: basicly should be the same result as horse answer but he use a `datarange` I didnt knew.

Answer (score 0):

The Valid_To column is obviously redundant and I highly recommend removing it from the table.

To get the latest price for an order date use a cross apply top 1 query:

```
select o.sku, o.price, o.date, cx.cost
from order o
cross join lateral
(
  select cost 
  from  costs c
  where c.sku = o.sku and c.valid_from <= o.date
  order by date desc
  limit 1
) cx;
```

Comment: There is no `cross apply` in Postgres. It uses the SQL standard's `cross join lateral`. And I disagree that the `valid_to` is redundant: it can be used to create constraint to prevent overlapping validity intervals

Comment: Why you say `valid_to` is redundant?

Comment: With a newer valid_from record the former valid_from gets out of date automatically. You have one entry for ABC1 / 2016-11-01 and one for ABC1 / 2016-10-01. So obviously there was one price valid from 2016-10-01 until the very day before 2016-11-01. If you additionally store this date as Valid_To in the record, you can make mistakes and store for instance 2016-11-01 and suddenly have two valid prices for the same day. Remove the redundant column to avoid such data inconsistencies.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Yes, because there are two orders on ABC1, and for each we are looking up the cost at the order day.